# Diverging pressure lines on $T$-$s$ diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

Can anybody mathematically prove why isobaric lines diverge as we increase temperature on a $T$-$s$ diagram?
I could end up reaching the point where $$(\partial T/ \partial s)_p = T/C_p  $$
But cannot deduce why Cp would decrease with an increase in pressure at the same temperature.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the partial derivative of Cp with respect to P at constant T from PVT data?

Comment: I didn't understand how I'd do it from PVT data, but I know using Maxwell's relations and basic differential calculus that-
(delCp/delP) at const T = -T(double derivative of volume wrt T ) at const P.
However, I don't know how to comment on the sign of the derivative of Cp wrt P to deduce whether Cp is an increasing or decreasing function of pressure.

Comment: This is correct. Now substitute PV=ZRT into your equation, and determine the result in terms of derivatives of Z. Then go to a corresponding states plot of Z as a function of reduced P and reduced T, and see if you can use that to determine what you are seeing on the T-S graph.